# How to respond to AWS Cognito DEVICE_SRP_AUTH for remember/trust device feature?

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have AWS Cognito based auth implementation on a Node App (Server-side, not using Amplify.

I have been using `adminInitiateAuth` with AuthFlow `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH` and it gives `SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA` in ChallengeName for MFA which is working well.

Now I need remember/trust this device functionality.

For that, once I send `DEVICE_KEY` in `adminInitiateAuth`, I get `DEVICE_SRP_AUTH` as challenge.

I have tried using `adminRespondToAuthChallenge`

```
adminRespondToAuthChallenge({
      ClientId: clientId,
      UserPoolId: UserPoolId,
      ChallengeName: 'DEVICE_SRP_AUTH',
      ChallengeResponses: {
        PASSWORD_VERIFIER: "PasswordVerifier-used-when-doing-confirmDevice",
        USERNAME: "user-id-for-srp",
        DEVICE_KEY: "device-key"
      }
})
```

I get `SRP_A` is required error message. I am not quite sure how to get `SRP_A` in there and now I am not sure it it is even right way to do remember this device functionality

I was hoping if I get through this, it will skip MFA and give me auth tokens that I need.

Can anyone guide me through this.